# How to implement Bluetooth Connectivity Actively into multiple Activities using Application Class or Service Class

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, android-service, android-bluetooth

I am new to bluetooth connection process flow. I am working with a mini thermal printer Device for my android application. The Device has its own SDK.

When the activity finishes or gets destroyed my connection to device is being lost. How could I modify following code to prevent this from happening.

```
PrintDemo Activity

package com.zj.printdemo;
import com.zj.printdemo.R;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.zj.btsdk.BluetoothService;
import com.zj.btsdk.PrintPic;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.util.Log;


public class PrintDemo extends Activity {
    Button btnSearch;
    Button btnSendDraw;
    Button btnSend;
    Button btnClose;
    EditText edtContext;
    EditText edtPrint;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
    BluetoothService mService = null;
    BluetoothDevice con_dev = null;
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;  //��ȡ�豸��Ϣ



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mService = new BluetoothService(this, mHandler);
    //�����������˳�����
    if( mService.isAvailable() == false ){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }       
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //����δ��������
    if( mService.isBTopen() == false)
    {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
    try {
        btnSendDraw = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
        btnSendDraw.setOnClickListener(new ClickEvent());
        btnSearch = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new ClickEvent());
        btnSend = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new ClickEvent());
        btnClose = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new ClickEvent());
        edtContext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_content);
        btnClose.setEnabled(false);
        btnSend.setEnabled(false);
        btnSendDraw.setEnabled(false);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("������Ϣ",ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mService != null) 
        mService.stop();
    mService = null; 
}

class ClickEvent implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnSearch) {           
            Intent serverIntent = new Intent(PrintDemo.this,DeviceListActivity.class);      //��������һ����Ļ
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent,REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
        } else if (v == btnSend) {
            String msg = edtContext.getText().toString();
            if( msg.length() > 0 ){
                mService.sendMessage(msg+"\n", "GBK");
            }
        } else if (v == btnClose) {
            mService.stop();
        } else if (v == btnSendDraw) {
            String msg = "";
            String lang = getString(R.string.strLang);
            //printImage();

            byte[] cmd = new byte[3];
            cmd[0] = 0x1b;
            cmd[1] = 0x21;
            if((lang.compareTo("en")) == 0){    
                cmd[2] |= 0x10;
                mService.write(cmd);           //��������ģʽ
                mService.sendMessage("Congratulations!\n", "GBK"); 
                cmd[2] &= 0xEF;
                mService.write(cmd);           //ȡ�����ߡ�����ģʽ
                msg = "  You have sucessfully created communications between your device and our bluetooth printer.\n\n"
                      +"  the company is a high-tech enterprise which specializes" +
                      " in R&D,manufacturing,marketing of thermal printers and barcode scanners.\n\n";


                mService.sendMessage(msg,"GBK");
            }else if((lang.compareTo("ch")) == 0){
                cmd[2] |= 0x10;
                mService.write(cmd);           //��������ģʽ
                mService.sendMessage("��ϲ����\n", "GBK"); 
                cmd[2] &= 0xEF;
                mService.write(cmd);           //ȡ�����ߡ�����ģʽ
                msg = "  ���Ѿ��ɹ��������������ǵ�������ӡ����\n\n"
                + "  ����˾��һ��רҵ�����з�����������������Ʊ�ݴ�ӡ��������ɨ���豸��һ��ĸ߿Ƽ���ҵ.\n\n";

                mService.sendMessage(msg,"GBK");    
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * ����һ��Handlerʵ�������ڽ���BluetoothService�෵�ػ�������Ϣ
 */
private final  Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case BluetoothService.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            switch (msg.arg1) {
            case BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED:   //������
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connect successful",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnClose.setEnabled(true);
                btnSend.setEnabled(true);
                btnSendDraw.setEnabled(true);
                break;
            case BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTING:  //��������
                Log.d("��������","��������.....");
                break;
            case BluetoothService.STATE_LISTEN:     //�������ӵĵ���
            case BluetoothService.STATE_NONE:
                Log.d("��������","�ȴ�����.....");
                break;
            }
            break;
        case BluetoothService.MESSAGE_CONNECTION_LOST:    //�����ѶϿ�����
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device connection was lost",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btnClose.setEnabled(false);
            btnSend.setEnabled(false);
            btnSendDraw.setEnabled(false);
            break;
        case BluetoothService.MESSAGE_UNABLE_CONNECT:     //�޷������豸
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect device",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }

};

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:      //���������
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {   //�����Ѿ���
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth open successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {                 //�û������������
            finish();
        }
        break;
    case  REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:     //��������ĳһ�����豸
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {   //�ѵ�������б��е�ĳ���豸��
            String address = data.getExtras()
                                 .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);  //��ȡ�б������豸��mac��ַ
            con_dev = mService.getDevByMac(address);   

            mService.connect(con_dev);
        }
        break;
    }
} 

//��ӡͼ��
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
private void printImage() {
    byte[] sendData = null;
    PrintPic pg = new PrintPic();
    pg.initCanvas(384);     
    pg.initPaint();
    pg.drawImage(0, 0, "/mnt/sdcard/icon.jpg");
    sendData = pg.printDraw();
    mService.write(sendData);   //��ӡbyte������
}
}
```

DeviceListActivity

```
 public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {
// Return Intent extra
public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

// Member fields
BluetoothService mService = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Setup the window
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.device_list);   //��ʾ�б����

    // Set result CANCELED incase the user backs out
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

    // Initialize the button to perform device discovery
    Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
    scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doDiscovery();
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    // Initialize array adapters. One for already paired devices and
    // one for newly discovered devices
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);
    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);

    // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
    ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
    pairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
    pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

    // Find and set up the ListView for newly discovered devices
    ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
    newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
    newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

    // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    mService = new BluetoothService(this, null);

    // Get a set of currently paired devices
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mService.getPairedDev();

    // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    } else {
        String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mService != null) {
        mService.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    mService = null;
    this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

/**
 * Start device discover with the BluetoothAdapter
 */
private void doDiscovery() {

    // Indicate scanning in the title
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setTitle(R.string.scanning);

    // Turn on sub-title for new devices
    findViewById(R.id.title_new_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // If we're already discovering, stop it
    if (mService.isDiscovering()) {
        mService.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
    mService.startDiscovery();
}

// The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {   //����б�������豸
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
        mService.cancelDiscovery();

        // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

        // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);
        Log.d("���ӵ�ַ", address);

        // Set result and finish this Activity
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
};

// The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and
// changes the title when discovery is finished
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            setTitle(R.string.select_device);
            if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }
    }
};

 }
```

I tried to remove the `onDestroy`, but it seems not work.

Answer (score 0):

Activities in Android are designed to provide user interface. Therefore, once an activity goes in the background, the system may stop it anytime. When activity stops, anything it was doing would be stopped too.

If you don't need any user interaction and just need to maintain Bluetooth connection in the background, you should use a service. The activity needs to launch a service and let it run. Even if the activity stops after this, the service would keep running.

There are two things to keep running a service indefinitely; create the service using startService() and return START_STICKY from onStartCommand(). With these two steps, the service may be shut down by the system but it should restart almost immediately.

Google doc has an example of implementing this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService